# Which does the word "unarmed" describe in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> The soldiers attacked the civilians unarmed.

Which does the word "unarmed" describe in the sentence, the soldiers or the civilians?

Comment: Tell us what you think, and why.

Comment: Hello Sanda,  What is the source of the quote?  Please tell us the website, book or article you read this on.

Comment: @James K Someone I know who was talking about the event said this. In the actual event the soldiers were armed and the civilians were unarmed, so I know the person meant unarmed civilians, not unarmed soldiers, but I wondered if the sentence meant that grammatically because to me it seemed ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The soldiers attacked the civilians unarmed.

makes no sense in standard English.

> The soldiers attacked the unarmed civilians.

Means the civilians had no weapons to defend themselves.

> The unarmed soldiers attacked the civilians.

Means the soldiers did not have any weapons when they attacked the civilians.

Answer (score 0):

In this position, the word "unarmed" would have to be an adverb and describe the attack. If the attack is unarmed, then the attackers would have to be unarmed, and so the soldiers would be unarmed (or at least not using their weapons in the attack). It is not ambiguous, it is clear that the attackers did not use arms.

> The special forces did not want to make a noise that would alert rest of the battalion, so they didn't use their guns and attacked the patrol unarmed.

It could also be a simple mistake (as the OP suggests) for "unarmed civilians" which is a common expression.